# Download a File from within the Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I only recently started working with the ASP.NET MVC 4 framework so this may be very trivial.

**Basically there are a some excel**(xlsx) **files within the project that I need to be able to download from the site.**

I'm currently doing this

***HTML***

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadTemplate", "Data", new { importToRun = item.Key })"></a>
```

***Controller***

```
public ActionResult DownloadTemplate(string importToRun)
{
    string document = Server.MapPath("~/Infrastructure/document.xlsx");
    string type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    return File(document, type, importToRun);
}
```

*I don't see what is wrong exactly and when I click the link it says that it couldn't find the file at the specified directory even though it is right and the file is there.*

*I'm thinking that it's a different procedure if your downloading a file from the project/solution.*

*I've had a very good look online and any help with be very appreciated.*

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to verify the path at runtime?

Comment: must you be in debug mode

Comment: Is this on your development machine or on a production server?

Comment: Yes, hit F9 to put a breakpoint on the Return File line, then launch the application in Debug Mode.  When that action triggers, it will switch you over to the line in the debugger.  Mouse over document to see it's value, make sure the path is correct.

Comment: maybe try putting the fully qualified path just to see if it works. the errors sounds like the MapPath isnt giving you the path you expect.

Comment: ya i'll try that, that might be it

Comment: Learning to use the debugger properly would reveal the same thing, and will be valuable in the future.  Stepping through is your best friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help the problem was the path.

I was referencing a place in the solution when I needed to reference the web url, it works perfect now

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. So I would think the problem is with the file.

1. Is there a folder within your website's root named "Infrastructure"?
2. Try putting the file in the "/App_Data" folder. The way you have the xlsx file right now, someone who knows the path can download it directly. Files in the App_Data directory cannot be accessed directly by the user.